# How can I check if my 2D character is in the air in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I'm trying to make my 2D character jump.
If I'm running on the ground it works perfectly, but when I collide with a wall, it gets buggy: I can jump even in the air.
I've tried solving this with a bool variable, but it didn't work.
I thought about checking whether the player is in the air and then setting the is_on_ground variable to false.
Obviusly, the player should only jump if it's on the ground.
My code is the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool canJump = false;
    public SpriteRenderer sr;
    private bool facingRight;
    private Animator animator;
    private bool is_on_ground;
    public Button leftBtn;
    public Button rightBtn;
    public Button jumpBtn;
    public float max_velocity;
    public float velocity;
    public float jump_scalar;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float x_movement;
    private Vector2 movement;
    void Start() {
        canJump = true;
        facingRight = true;
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        leftBtn.onClick.AddListener(moveLeft);
        rightBtn.onClick.AddListener(moveRight);
        jumpBtn.onClick.AddListener(jump);
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if (rb.velocity.magnitude < max_velocity) {
            movement = new Vector2(x_movement, 0);
            rb.AddForce(movement * velocity);
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (CollisionIsWithGround(collision)) {
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            canJump = true;
        }
        if (collision.collider.tag == "wall") {
            canJump = false;
        }
        is_on_ground = true;

    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (!CollisionIsWithGround(collision)) {
            is_on_ground = false;
        }
        if (collision.collider.tag == "wall") {
            is_on_ground = true;
            canJump = true;
        }
    }
    private bool CollisionIsWithGround(Collision2D collision) {
        bool is_with_ground = false;
        foreach (ContactPoint2D c in collision.contacts) {
            Vector2 collision_direction_vector = c.point - rb.position;
            if(collision_direction_vector.y < 0) {
                is_with_ground = true;
            }
        }
        return is_with_ground;
    }
    public void moveLeft() {
        if (is_on_ground) {
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        sr.flipX = true;
        facingRight = false;
        x_movement = -1;
    }
    public void onRelease() {
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        x_movement = 0;
        if(is_on_ground) {
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
    public void moveRight() {
        if (is_on_ground) {
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }
        if (!facingRight) {
            sr.flipX = false;
            facingRight = true;
            animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        } else {
            animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        x_movement = 1;
    }
    public void jump() {
        if(is_on_ground) {
            if (canJump) {
                animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
                Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, jump_scalar * 100);
                rb.AddForce(jumpForce);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[the problem looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQrmU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a raycast straight down, you could also cast a circle around the player's feet.

You will need to add an empty ground check game object as a child of your player and position its transform at the player's feet. Next, you will need to define what layers count as the ground in the inspector for the `m_WhatIsGround` LayerMask.

Then in `FixedUpdate()` check if the ground check transform is within some radius to the ground.

```
// A mask determining what is ground to the character
[SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;

// A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
[SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;

// Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
const float k_GroundedRadius = 0.3f;

private void FixedUpdate() {
    is_on_ground = false;

    // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
    // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++) {
        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject) {
            is_on_ground = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A tutorial on this method can be found in this [Brackey's video](https://youtu.be/dwcT-Dch0bA?t=180).

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a [Physics2d.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) to the floor in every `FixedUpdate`. When the range to the nearest object is smaller than 0.01 or something like this than you would test if its the floor and if it is then set the `is_on_ground = true` and when it is not then perform `is_on_ground = false`

**Example:**

```cs
float raycastDistance = 0.05f;
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, raycastDistance);
if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("ground"))
    is_on_ground = true;
} else {
    is_on_ground = false;
}
```

This should work. You obviously have to define a layer named ground in this example and add it to every ground.

Comment: Can you give me more information about how can I use that here?

Comment: @Chr added an example

Comment: The is_on_ground variable keeps staying false now.

Comment: The hit.transform.gameObject.layer gives me the layer of the player.

Comment: @Chr you have to perform the raycast from the botton of the character. You could for example add an subobject which is directly at the feet. You perform the raycast from its postion. The object should not have a colider.

Comment: @Chr otherwise you could also work with Layermasks from the raycast. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html